# Ionic - Zooming on inline SVG element

Tags: javascript, angular, svg, ionic2, touch

I've got an Ionic app with an inline SVG map (it has to be inline since there's functionality provided in the SVG).

I could post all the SVG code, but since it's 1000 rules, I think that's a little much.. Here's what I've got:

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar color='primary'>
        <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
        <ion-title>Plattegrond</ion-title>
        <ion-buttons end>
            <button ion-button icon-only (click)="openPopover($event)">
        <ion-icon name="more"></ion-icon>
      </button>
        </ion-buttons>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content style="background-color: #000;">
    <ion-scroll zooming="true" direction="xy">
         <svg>
             //svg element
         </svg>
    </ion-scroll>
</ion-content>
```

The outcome is this SVG element:

[image]

For some reason I can't zoom in on the SVG element with this piece of code, which should just work..

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem, did you manage to fix it? any alternative solution? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check [`ion-scroll`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/scroll/Scroll/) API.

You have set incorrect attributes:

```
<ion-content style="background-color: #000;">
    <ion-scroll zoom="true" scrollX="true" scrollY="true">
         <svg>
             //svg element
         </svg>
    </ion-scroll>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: doesnt work meaning? doesnt scroll? or the content doesnt show?

Comment: do you have `ion-scroll { white-space: nowrap; }` set?

Comment: try setting `maxZoom` attribute

Comment: added the `maxZoom` attribute.. didn't fix it.. Also added a preference and changed my viewport meta tag..